# How to fix " Failed to mount /system_root (invalid arguement)

Tags: recovery

I have tried fixing this problem for hours but am unable to find a solution.

When i try to mount System partition, Vendor and product it gives me

Failed to mount '/system_root' (invalid argument)
Failed to mount '/vendor' (invalid argument)
Failed to mount '/product' (Invalid argument)

Device: Redmi note 9S Curtana

recovery: PBRP-3.1.0-OFFICIAL

Please tell me how to fix this. Thanks

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Is your TWRP updated to the last version?

Answer (score 0):

If you already didn't update your TWRP update it to the lastest version.

After that click on the Mount(under Backup, above Advanced) option, after you clicked on that there should be options called *"Cache, System, Vendor, Data, Firmware, Persist, USB-OTG"*.
From here, *unselect* the **Mount system partition is read-only** option then select all of them **except for the USB-OTG.** Then you can continue your recovery.

Keep me updated. Hope it works!